# Is $Cov(X,|X|)=VarX$ when $X\sim \{-1,0,+1\}$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X \sim Uniform \{-1,0,+1\}$ and let $Y=|X|$. Compute $Cov(X,Y)$.

I tried to substitute. Can I do this? $Cov(X,Y)=Cov(X,|X|)=VarX$ 
How to solve this problem? I'm confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\Cov{\mathop{\rm Cov}\nolimits}\def\Var{\mathop{\rm Var}\nolimits}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$Of course you have $\Cov(X,Y) = \Cov(X,\abs X)$ for $Y = \abs X$. Moreover we have as $X \sim {\rm Unif}(\{-1,0,1\})$ that $\abs X = X^2$ and $X^3 = X$, hence 
$$ E[X\abs X] = E[X^3] = E[X] = 0 $$
and hence 
$$ \Cov(X, \abs X) = E[X\abs X] - E[X]E[\abs X] = 0 $$
but $\Var (X) \ne 0$.

Comment: So, can I say they are independent?

Comment: No. Uncorrelated. They are dependent as $P[\abs X = 0 , X = 1] = 0 \ne P[\abs X = 0]P[X = 1]$.